# I am trying to print props in console but when i write console.log(props.details) it prints it twice in console

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Once I render this functional component and open the console to check if props are present or not.
The console shows me props containing array two times but the first time printed array is empty and the array that was printed the second time contains the data. I am really confused and unable to debug this error.

Below is the code:

```
const MainConents = (props) => {
        console.log(props.details);
    return ( 
        <>
            <div className="container" style={{marginTop : "20px"}}>
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-12">
                            // show single post in loop wise from database
                            // show pagination for posts
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </>
    );
}

export default MainConents;
```

The output in my browser is:

[this is the link of image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7IbPL.png)

Comment: [Don't show pictures of text](/help/how-to-ask). Just put the text in your post, with code markup.

Answer (score 0):

`props` are passed from a parent component and I believe these `details` are fetched by invoking an api endpoint.

Therefore, during the initial rendering backend server didn't respond back with a response and as a result, it will show an empty array at the beginning (which is initial value of `props.details`). But when it sends the response, `props.details` are now updated and as a result child component `MainConents` will be re-rendered. Then, it will show the updated array in the console logs.

Therefore, initially you'll see an empty array and then the updated `props.details`.

If you only need to print the array when it's not empty. Then you can put a simple condition as follows. (But it's not necessary, because console logs are only used for debug purposes)

```
if(props.details.length > 0){
console.log(props.details);
}
```

Comment: Now, the backend will definitely take its time to fetch the data. Which can be shown instead of data on the front end page while fetching data.

Comment: There isn't any solution. That's the way react behaves. Re-rendering happens whenever `props` or `state` changes happen. And it is fine. Because, it should happen, otherwise it won't update the actual DOM.